# Delayed jobs stop web interface from working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

In my local version there is a background process running delayed jobs. I use background jobs to allow web interface to be accessed while server allocates resources to do work in background. But it does not seem to, as while delayed jobs are running I am unable to access the website (browser keeps showing animated loading bar).

I ran rake jobs:work instead of script/delayed_job start. When I run:

```
script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start
ruby RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start
ruby script/delayed_job start
```

I get:

```
-bash: script/delayed_job: No such file or directory
-bash: script/delayed_job: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- RAILS_ENV=development (LoadError)
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/delayed_job (LoadError)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't installed the script command. You have to run this:

```
> rails g delayed_job:active_record
```

After that you can use it normally, as the files will be created, as follows:
(output)

```
     create  script/delayed_job
     chmod  script/delayed_job
     create  db/migrate/20120109185353_create_delayed_jobs.rb
```

Reference: http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised?view=asciicast